# order of Center of General Linear Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G = Gl_n(\mathbb{C})$  where $Gl_n$ = General Linear group of order $n$ and  \mathbb{C} = Complex Numbers , then $|Z( Gl_n(\mathbb{C}))| = {?}$

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQhOM.jpg)

Comment: This question boils down to a problem from Halmos's *Finite-Dimensional Vector spaces*: on which vector spaces does there exist a linear transformation that commutes with all the others and is not a scalar multiple of the identity transformation?  Answer: only on 1-dimensional spaces.  For dimension $\geq 2$, you can always exhibit a linear transformation that fails to commute with at least one other.

Answer (score 1):

Any nonzero multiple of the identity matrix is in the center, so $|Z(G)| = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

(In fact, nothing else is in the center.)

Comment: can't get it , Please explain

Comment: Which part don't you get?

Comment: you mean there's nothing in the center?

Comment: No, I said that any nonzero multiple $zI, z \ne 0$ of the identity is in the center. (And then in parentheses, I claimed that every element of the center has this form. But you don't need to know this to know the order of the center is infinite.)

Comment: if there is a General linear group over complex numbers then number of elements in its center is infinite?

Comment: @AakashRastogi, sounds like you could do more linear algebra first.  Look into P. Halmos's *Finite-dimensional vector spaces*, and the companion *Linear algebra problem book*.